# Interested in differentiate square and rectangle in an image without using openCV

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I have an image which consist of rectangle and square, Now I am interested in distinguish  which one is rectangle and which one is square in that image. I have used Harris corner detection algorithm to extract the corner points. Using these corner point I am able to extract the index of these corner pixel. The next task I am interested is differentiate which one is rectangle and which one is square? I Know the conditions for square `height=width`. Using this information I wanted to execute the differentiation.

[image: OD6]

```
mport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import matplotlib.image as im   
from scipy import ndimage


# 1. Before doing any operations convert the image into gray scale image

img = im.imread('OD6.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

# split
R=img[:,:,0]
G=img[:,:,1]
B=img[:,:,2]


M,N=R.shape

gray_img=np.zeros((M,N), dtype=int);

for i in range(M):                     
        for j in range(N):
            gray_img[i, j]=(R[i, j]*0.2989)+(G[i, j]*0.5870)+(B[i, j]*0.114);

plt.imshow(gray_img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

# 2. Applying sobel filter to find the gradients in x and y direction respectively and remove noise
# using gaussian filter with sigma=1 

imarr = np.asarray(gray_img, dtype=np.float64)
ix = ndimage.sobel(imarr, 0)
iy = ndimage.sobel(imarr, 1)
ix2 = ix * ix
iy2 = iy * iy
ixy = ix * iy
ix2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(ix2, sigma=1)
iy2 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(iy2, sigma=1)
ixy = ndimage.gaussian_filter(ixy, sigma=1)
c, l = imarr.shape
result = np.zeros((c, l))
r = np.zeros((c, l))

rmax = 0 # initialize the maximum value of harris response
for i in range(c):
        for j in range(l):
            m = np.array([[ix2[i, j], ixy[i, j]], [ixy[i, j], iy2[i, j]]], dtype=np.float64)
            r[i, j] = np.linalg.det(m) - 0.04 * (np.power(np.trace(m), 2))
            if r[i, j] > rmax:
                rmax = r[i, j]

# 3. Applying non maximum supression
for i in range(c - 1):
        for j in range(l - 1):
            if r[i, j] > 0.01 * rmax and r[i, j] > r[i-1, j-1] and r[i, j] > r[i-1, j+1]\
                                     and r[i, j] > r[i+1, j-1] and r[i, j] > r[i+1, j+1]:
                result[i, j] = 1


xy_coords = np.flip(np.column_stack(np.where(result==1)), axis=1)
print (xy_coords)

pc, pr = np.where(result == 1)
plt.plot(pr, pc, "b.")  
plt.imshow(img, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the objection to OpenCV please? Also, rather than using lossy JPEG, did you consider using PNG so that your values are exactly preserved during processing?

Comment: @MarkSetchell if I start using OpenCV then I wont understand how function in cv2 works. More over I am interested in learning from scratch. What is the advantage with PNG over JPEG could you please elaborate?

Comment: There are many advantages to PNG. 1) It can handle 16-bits/sample whereas JPEG can only handle 8-bits 2) It is loss-less, so you get back exactly the values you write, whereas if you create a pure red rectangle on a pure blue background and save as JPEG, you will probably get an image with hundreds of colours if you save as JPEG and read back from disk. 3) It can handle transparency. 4) It can natively and easily handle greyscale images.